# String array initialization in dynamically through excel file column and rows

Tags: java

my code is read a excel file and store data in two dimensional String array through dynamically initialization  and then print that String array when i run this code java.lang.NullPointerException is raised . if i ininitialization array in static method it work good but i want  array initialization in dynamically

excel file
age     place
32  chennai
31  new york
55  indiana
12  lohoas
13  mumbai
111 pune
45  los angel

java code

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

    JFileChooser open = new JFileChooser();
    open.showOpenDialog(null);
    File f = open.getSelectedFile();
    String filepath = f.getAbsolutePath();
    jTextField1.setText(filepath);
    try {
        Workbook wb = Workbook.getWorkbook(f);
        Sheet sh = wb.getSheet(0);
        int row = sh.getRows();
        int col = sh.getColumns();

        String[][] ss = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= col; j++) {

                Cell c2 = sh.getCell(j, i);
                System.out.print(c2.getContents() + "\t");
                ss[j][i] = c2.getContents();

            }
            System.out.print("\n");
        }

        System.out.println("array");
        for (int i = 0; i < ss.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < ss.length; j++) {
                System.out.print(ss[i][j] + "\t");
            }
        }

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(rdwr.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (BiffException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(rdwr.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
```

Comment: your suggested link describe only static intialization   method but i want dynamic  intialization

Answer (score 0):

I think in your inner for loop of col you have use <= which is causing an issue.

replace this

```
for (int j = 0; j <= col; j++) {
```

with

```
for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
```